# Rails mailer set url to object on email sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a mailer to send out email when object is  created.Email is sent out fine.

This is the template:

```
<h4>A new poll was created, <%= @poll.question %></h4>

Check it at <%= polls_url(@poll) %>

<p>Have a great day!</p>
```

The result n email I receive is:

```
A new poll was created, Question?
Check it at http://example.com/polls.88

Have a great day!
```

below is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :bugs
    resources :projects do
      resources :project_lines do
        post 'accept', :on => :member
        post 'start', :on => :member
        post 'complete', :on => :member
        post 'approve', :on => :member
        post 'pay', :on => :member
      end
    end
    resources :projects do
      resources :project_expenses do
        post 'approve', :on => :member
        post 'pay', :on => :member
      end
    end
    resources :clients
    get 'poll_excluded_users/create'


    resources :polls do
      resources :comments
      collection { post :import }
    end

    resources :comments do
      resources :comments
    end

    devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'

    root to: "polls#open_polls"

end
```

Why is it setting the URL to `polls.88` instead of `polls/88`? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Gotta show your `routes.rb` for this one. You get a `.88` if your URI did not expect an `/:id` part, for example...

Comment: Something wrong with your `routes.rb` file please post your `routes.rb`

Comment: Thanks I posted routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loo, if you run `rake routes` or `rails routes` for seeing routing then it showing

```
    poll_comments GET    /polls/:poll_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /polls/:poll_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_poll_comment GET    /polls/:poll_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_poll_comment GET    /polls/:poll_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     poll_comment GET    /polls/:poll_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /polls/:poll_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /polls/:poll_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /polls/:poll_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
     import_polls POST   /polls/import(.:format)                     polls#import
            polls GET    /polls(.:format)                            polls#index
                  POST   /polls(.:format)                            polls#create
         new_poll GET    /polls/new(.:format)                        polls#new
        edit_poll GET    /polls/:id/edit(.:format)                   polls#edit
             poll GET    /polls/:id(.:format)                        polls#show
                  PATCH  /polls/:id(.:format)                        polls#update
                  PUT    /polls/:id(.:format)                        polls#update
                  DELETE /polls/:id(.:format)                        polls#destroy
```

That means your single `poll` show path is below

```
poll GET    /polls/:id(.:format)                        polls#show
```

then it will to be the email template `poll_url` it's not `polls_url`, it will show `(poll_url)` something like this `www.example.com/pools/88`

Comment: I changed to <%= poll_url(@poll) %> and it worked. Thanks!